# Mistakenly worked in someone else's branch from my team in Azure Devops. Confused regarding pushing my changes to the server

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, push

I worked in someone else's branch instead of mine and when I try to push it to the server, I am unable to do so. When I try to commit and push I get the following error. Please help.[image: Visual Studio Screen Shot]

Comment: See the Pull and Push button? Click it...

Comment: You have to update your question to tell us what you want to do: 1) Still want to push in the other dev branch (button "Pull and Push" but if that's another branch, I don't think that's not what you want to do) or 2) you want to stop what you did wrong and fix everything to push in your branch (In this case, button "Cancel" and a lot of other steps requiring more information). But if you don't understand why you get this popup, surely you have to read some documentation to at least understand the git basics....

Comment: Hi @Anas, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message: Update your branch by pulling before push, we need update your local branch via `git pull` and then push the change to Azure DevOps Repo. Also, we could do this via the button `Pull and Push`

**Update1**

Thanks for Philippe‘s sharing.

We should know that a pull is doing a merge by default and that most of the times, when you work in your own branch, you prefer to sync with a rebase. So this popup won't help.

Comment: But @Anas should know that a `pull` is doing a `merge` by default and that most of the times, when you work in your own branch, you prefer to sync with a `rebase`. So this popup won't help.

Comment: @Philippe. Thank you so much for the information